# Shaded area between curves in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have several curves defined by the same x-values, but different y-values. The image below consists of 21 different curves. 10 of them is dotted lines, 1 is solid, and the last 10 is dashed.

However, as can be seen in the image, it's rather much in one graph. You can't really see what is what everywhere. So what I would like is having a shaded area between the first 10 lines as well as the last 10, which I think would make it a lot easier on the eyes.

But I'm not quite sure how to begin?

As it is now the my code is as follows:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

structures = ['Rectum']
patients = ["426"]

color_map = 'nipy_spectral'
color = {'PTV':0.16, 'Rectum':0.80, 'Bladder':0.96}

legends = ['PTV', 'Rectum', 'Bladder']

x = np.loadtxt('dose_gy.txt')


for plot, patient in enumerate(patients):
    plot += 1
    PATH_TO_YDATA = 'results/Two_Fields/DVH'
    for f in sorted(os.listdir(PATH_TO_YDATA), key=lambda f: f.split('_')[-2]):
        if f.split('_')[-2] == patient:
            for structure in structures:
                if f.split('_')[2] == structure:
                    y = np.loadtxt(PATH_TO_YDATA + '/' + f)
                    plt.axis([0, 90, 0, 50])
                    if int(f.split('_')[-1][:-4]) < 90:
                        plt.plot(x, y * 100, color=plt.get_cmap(color_map)(color[structure]), linestyle='dotted', alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0)
                    elif int(f.split('_')[-1][:-4]) > 90:
                        plt.plot(x, y * 100, color=plt.get_cmap(color_map)(color[structure]), linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0)
                    elif int(f.split('_')[-1][:-4]) == 90:
                        plt.plot(x, y * 100, color=plt.get_cmap(color_map)(color[structure]), linestyle='solid', alpha=1.0, linewidth=3.0, zorder=1000)
    plt.title('Patient ' + str(plot))
    plt.xlabel("Dose [Gy]", fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel("Volume [%]", fontsize=14)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: [fill_between()](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html)

Comment: I've tried looking at this now. But it seems that it is only valid for maybe two lines ? In this case, I don't know in advance which line will be the lowest, and if it will be the lowest at all point, hence, when that happens, the shading should start from the line that is currently the lowest in that point, to the point that is highest at that point.

Answer (score 7):

In order to fill between the minimum and maximum of several curves you need to determine the array that represents the minimal or maximal value for each point along the curve. If all curves share the same x values, this is pretty easily done by taking the minimum along one axis of the combined y values. E.g.

```
np.min(np.c_[y1, y2, y3, ...], axis=1)
```

Same for maximum. Then `fill_between` can be used with those combined arrays as input.

A complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(4)

# generate some data to plot
x = np.linspace(0.8,10,201)
f = lambda x, p1,p2,p3,p4: p1/x + np.sinc(x*p4)*p3 + p2
Y = np.empty((len(x), 9))
P1 = 1.5+ (np.random.normal(size=9)-0.5)*0.2
P2 = np.linspace(0.9,1.1, 9)
P3 = 1+ (np.random.normal(size=9)-0.5)*0.2
P4 = np.linspace(0.9,1.1, 9)+ (np.random.normal(size=9)-0.5)
for i in range(9):
    Y[:,i] = f(x,P1[i], P2[i], P3[i], P4[i])

# plot    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

style= [":"]*4 + ["-"] + ["--"]*4
colors = ["crimson"]*4 + ["k"] + ["#9a0bad"]*4
lw = np.ones(9); lw[4] = 2
for i in range(9):
    ax.plot(x,Y[:,i], linestyle=style[i], label="curve "+str(i), lw=lw[i], color=colors[i])

Y1min = np.min(Y[:,:4], axis=1)
Y1max = np.max(Y[:,:4], axis=1)
Y2min = np.min(Y[:,5:], axis=1)
Y2max = np.max(Y[:,5:], axis=1)

ax.fill_between(x, Y1max, Y1min, color="crimson", alpha=0.4)
ax.fill_between(x, Y2max, Y2min, color="#9a0bad", alpha=0.4)

plt.show()
```

[image]