# Add two lists and return a new list with the highest value

Tags: python

So let's say I have two lists hat looks like this:

```
x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x2 = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

I now wish to add them together into a new list, but with the twist that the new list contains the highest (or lowest) value from each.

So if I need the highest values the resulting new list would become:

```
final_list_highest = [9,8,7,6,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And for the lowest values:

```
final_list_lowest = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Hopefully, you see where I'm going :)

Is there some neat easy trick to do this that I just haven't figured out, or how would you about doing it?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements in the final lists? Or only that they contain the highest/lowest values?

Comment: This looks like a question ripe for 8 answers ;) You could use `lows, highs = zip(*map(sorted,list(zip(x1, x2))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line

```
min_list, max_list = zip(*[(min(a,b),max(a,b)) for a,b in zip(x1,x2)])
```

This assumes that the lists are of the same size. You could use `sorted()` instead of max/min and maybe it would be slightly faster but I find this more readable.

Comment: How would a loop go when using this min and max ? Let's say I have 100 lists, and I wish to create one list with the highest values from all 100 lists, and lowest. I'm really not sure how a loop would work here...

Comment: By loop you mean a "for-loop"?

Answer (score 1):

```
final_list_highest = [max(a, b) for a, b in zip(x1, x2)]
```

should give a list with the highest values.

Use `min` to get the lowest values.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem originates from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553737/shaded-area-between-curves-in-plot), it's save to assume that **numpy** can be used. A solution is therefore to use `numpy.min` and `numpy.max` together with a specified axes.

```
import numpy as np

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x2 = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

print (np.c_[x1,x2].min(axis=1)) # prints [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1]
print (np.c_[x1,x2].max(axis=1)) # prints [9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9]
```